# Storage size of 'i1' isn't known

Tags: c

*it showing error in `union item i1;`*
*it says storage size of i1 isn't known*
*how to recover from this error*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    union item i1;     
    i1.x = 5;
    printf("\n%d",i1.x);
    i1.y = 3.5;
    printf("\n%f",i1.y);
    strcpy(i1.z,"C Programming");
    printf("\n%s",i1.z);
    return 0;
}
union item
{
    int x;
    float y;
    char z[20];
};
```

**please solve this problem**

Comment: You need to declare things before you use them.

Comment: The definition of the `union` type needs to be *before* the declaration of `i1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the definition of `item` before declaring it in `main()`, otherwise the compiler will view it as an incomplete (undefined) type. This should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
union item
{
    int x;
    float y;
    char z[20];
};
int main()
{
    union item i1;     
    i1.x = 5;
    printf("\n%d",i1.x);
    i1.y = 3.5;
    printf("\n%f",i1.y);
    strcpy(i1.z,"C Programming");
    printf("\n%s",i1.z);
    return 0;
}
```